# When will the applications submitted to the Ubuntu App Showdown be available for download via the Software Centre?

Tags: software-center, application-development

The deadline for submitting applications has passed and now the applications are being reviewed. OMG! Ubuntu points out that the applications will be available on the Software Centre by the end of this week, however it doesn't seem like the judges will review all the applications and pick the winners any time soon. So, will the applications be available for download before the winners are announced? Is it true that they'll be available later this week? Or do we have to wait for the winners to be announced? If so, is there a specific date?

Comment: check here for updates http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/07/the-ubuntu-app-showdown-review-is-in-full-swing/

Comment: What makes you think that the judges won't review apps any time soon? Judges have actually started voting (announcement to come on that), and technical review of all apps by the Ubuntu App Review Board is happening in parallel. See http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/07/the-ubuntu-app-showdown-review-is-in-full-swing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## apps are now available in software center

Answer (score 4):

When all applications has been reviewed and accepted, your application gets into the USC.

The Ubuntu App Review Board has got 130 apps to review, ask about some mistakes in the apps etc. etc. etc. That takes much time (just calculate it: 130 apps * 20 minutes per app = 44 hours.).

Comment: **Edit:** Some of the apps are already in the USC. To get more info about that, [click here](https://plus.google.com/111697084657487423167/posts).